# Is there a way to check Google drive storage using Drive API for Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am currently using below component for a Xamarin app.

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleplayservices-drive

I tried uploading a file to a Google drive that has a full storage using above component and it seems to successfully upload and returns a successful response. When I retrieve all files in the drive's folder it seems to be there for a few seconds then disappears.

Answer (score 0):

> In some cases, applications may need to use the Google Drive web service to access additional features or access broader scopes than what is available in the Google Drive Android API.

Google does not expose the user's `Drive` storage quota within the `Android.Gms.Drive` api.

You will need to use the Rest APIs using an **Auth2 token** that has been authorization a Drive scope and call:

- https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about

With the Json response, you can access `storageQuota`:

```
{
 "storageQuota": {
  "limit": "16106127360",
  "usage": "3115832693",
  "usageInDrive": "373280402",
  "usageInDriveTrash": "46755721"
 }
}
```

Google Ref: [About: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get)